# cpu fan is always working and the air is hot

Tags: 16.04, cpu, fan

I have recently moved from windows 10 to ubuntu 16.04.

Cpu fan was always on in windows 10 because of bios setting but the air wasnt hot, in ubuntu the fan is always and the air is hot.

and my battery life is about 2hrs it used to be 4hrs on windows

Laptop: Hp 15r004ne, i have nvidia and i am using nvidia drivers

Comment: The overheat indicates something heavy is running in the background, open System monitor and  move to resources and see what's eating up your processor power. 

The power loss is actually common and can be mitigated by installing powertop and running it from the terminal `sudo apt-get install powertop`

Comment: nothing heavy is running

Comment: How high is your CPU usage? What are your specs?